# How to return recent values of grouped user_id?

Tags: postgresql

How can I make it so the results only return the last entry for each grouped user_id. Example below.

Also, any approach on improving the query will be much appreciated. `properties` is an hstore column.

```
SELECT user_id, json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'following')
ORDER BY id DESC) AS followings,
json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'assumed_gender') ORDER BY id DESC) AS assumed_genders,
json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'email') ORDER BY id DESC) AS emails,
json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'first_name') ORDER BY id DESC) AS first_names,
json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'last_name') ORDER BY id DESC) AS last_names,
json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'country_name') ORDER BY id DESC) AS country_names,
json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'city_name') ORDER BY id DESC) AS city_names,
json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'mobile_number') ORDER BY id DESC) AS mobile_numbers,
json_agg(to_json(properties -> 'submission_url') ORDER BY id DESC) AS submission_urls
FROM "daily_statistics" WHERE "daily_statistics"."campaign_id" = 72 AND "daily_statistics"."metric" = 'participation'
GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max(id) DESC;
```

The result:

```
 user_id |    followings     | assumed_genders |                emails                 |    first_names     |     last_names     |  country_names   |     city_names     |        mobile_number
s        |                         submission_urls
---------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+---------------------
---------+------------------------------------------------------------------
      16 | ["false", "true"] | ["", ""]        | ["lorem@lorem.com", "lorem@amet.com"] | ["dolor", "ipsum"] | ["lorem", "ipsum"] | ["amet", "amet"] | ["dolor", "ipsum"] | ["9707759365", "2572
943441"] | ["http://www.dolor.com/hgtsjcbn", "http://www.sit.com/qlnogrzd"]
(1 row)
```

Desired result:

```
 user_id |    followings     | assumed_genders |                emails                 |    first_names     |     last_names     |  country_names   |     city_names     |        mobile_number
s        |                         submission_urls
---------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+---------------------
---------+------------------------------------------------------------------
      16 | "true"            | ""              | "lorem@amet.com"                      | "ipsum"            | "ipsum"            | "amet"           | "ipsum"            |         "2572
943441"  | "http://www.sit.com/qlnogrzd"
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `distinct on`

```
select distinct on (user_id)
    user_id,
    to_json(properties -> 'following') as followings,
    to_json(properties -> 'assumed_gender') as assumed_genders,
    to_json(properties -> 'email') as emails,
    to_json(properties -> 'first_name') as first_names,
    to_json(properties -> 'last_name') as last_names,
    to_json(properties -> 'country_name') as country_names,
    to_json(properties -> 'city_name') as city_names,
    to_json(properties -> 'mobile_number') as mobile_numbers,
    to_json(properties -> 'submission_url') as submission_urls
from "daily_statistics"
where
    "daily_statistics"."campaign_id" = 72
    and "daily_statistics"."metric" = 'participation'
order by user_id, id desc
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first

Comment: This works, but what if I would like to retain one of the columns  (i.e. `submissions_urls`) as an array and not a unique distinct value? Is this possible?